# PHP cookies not accessible from www. subdomain

Tags: php, cookies

This cookie is not available to `www.domain.com` but is available to domain.com. Strange thing is that firefox sees the cookie in `www.domain.com` (Using the view info but my server does not recognize the cookie). I have done a decent amount of searching and  the only solution I found was to set the domain to `.domain.com` but then my cookies can not be read at `domain.com`.  Here is my code:

```
//this results in no access through domain.com
setcookie('username', $username, time()+3600*24, '/', '.domain.com');

//this results in domain.com access but not www.domain.com
setcookie('username', $username, time()+3600*24, '/');
```

What is the key to getting the cookie to be available to domain.com and all subdomains?

Comment: Have you tried `setcookie('username', $username, time()+3600*24, '/', 'domain.com');`

Comment: The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Comment: i read read that on the php guide and setting domain to domain.com, i can not access the cookie from domain.com, only www.domain.com

Comment: Are you removed (clean) and reseting cookie from a Web browser? Probably and another browser? On which platform do you work? Server?

Comment: Yes that was the issue! Ally my tweaking lead to my logout system not deleting old cookies properly thus cookies kept adding up! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

`setcookie('username', $username, time()+3600*24, '/', 'domain.com');`

Comment: this is not accessible to domain.com

Comment: that was the issue... as i said in my comment above all my tweaking lead to my logout system not deleting old cookies properly thus cookies kept adding up! thanks!